# Sidekiq Job rescue method return error in perform_async method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have defined a mailer job using sidekiq as below. The issue I am facing here is since I have defined the **VisitReminderWorker.perform_async(expense_ids)** as async job because of which I am not getting an error return from the worker.rb file. What I want is if there is an error on the worker file, it returns the error to the rake file in the rescue method. Any idea where I am going wrong.

office.rake

```
namespace :office do
  desc "send payment reminder emails"
  task send_payment_reminder: :environment do
    VisitReminderRun.create(status: :processing)
    reminder_run = VisitReminderRun.last
    visit_reminder_job_status = true
    Office.all.each do |office|      
      expense_ids = []
      office.issues.where("issues.amount > 0").each do |issue|
        expense = issue.expenses.order(:date, :id).last
        expense_ids << expense.id if expense.date < VisitReminderRun.last.created_at 
      end
      begin      
        VisitReminderWorker.perform_async(expense_ids)
      rescue StandardError => e
        visit_reminder_job_status = false
      end
    end
    if visit_reminder_job_status == false
      reminder_run.update(status: :failed) 
    else 
      reminder_run.update(status: :successful) 
    end
  end
end
```

visit_reminder_worker.rb

```
class VisitReminderWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  def perform(expense_ids)
    begin
      VisitReminderMailer.visit_reminder_letter(expense_ids).deliver_now
    rescue StandardError => e
      return e
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You cant do it because the `perform_async` method does not execute your worker's code but only schedules it for later. You can either execute it immediately by doing `VisitReminderWorker.new.perform(expense_ids)` and catch the error or you can handle exceptions asynchronously - which is a must because if your code runs asynchronously then obviously your exceptions will also be asynchronous.

One way would be to use some kind of exception tracker (like [Rollbar](https://rollbar.com) or [Stackdriver](https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/)). The other way would be to monitor your `Sidekiq::RetrySet` and `Sidekiq::DeadSet`, for example by using the [sidekiq web interface](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Monitoring#web-ui).

Comment: if I do VisitReminderWorker.new.perform(expense_ids) then it doesn't call the worker

Comment: It has to, it's just plain ruby.

Comment: I TRIED IT again. It calls the worker if I use perform_async and don't call if I use new.perform